# Windows 10: How do I make an application searchable?

Tags: windows, windows-10, search, cortana

For most applications I've installed, I can type "windows + q" and it pops up a search bar.  I can type in there and find an app.  But I've downloaded and installed [Notepad2](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html).  It's just an exe you drop anywhere.  Windows is not able to find this if I press "windows + q, notepad".

I use this program regularly and I'd like it to be searchable.  Is there a certain directory I could drop it into so that it's searchable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put a shortcut to the executable in `%programdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` and it should become searchable in the Start Menu.

Worth noting that, although it should become visible immediately in the Start Menu, it might take a while before you can search for it by just typing a couple of letters.

Comment: I just tried this solution on a Windows 10 installed recently (March 2019) and even after several days Win+q still cannot find my shortcut. Any idea if this feature is now broken? Does it still work for you?

Comment: @joanis Odd. I just added a shortcut to an exe I'd written (which wasn't previously in the Start Menu) to the path mentioned and it appeared as a result with Win+Q after about 5 minutes.

Comment: I just did more tests and I see some links get indexed and some not. The target of the link seems to matter: a link to `putty.exe` can be found, while a link to `chrome.exe` with a specific page to load cannot. Now, links in `C:\Users\<me>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` work more reliably than in `%programdata%\...`, but the bookmark-like browser shortcuts still don't get indexed. More weird, a shortcut to just `putty.exe` works, but not a shortcut with a given session: a shortcut to `...path...\putty.exe @host1` is not indexed. Frustratingly unreliable.